# Problem when deleting an element in material ui chip input

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design

I want to be able to limit the number of tags in chip input, this is solved, but now if I want to delete a chip, it does not seem like it's been deleted until I click again in the input

this is my code so far

```
var chips = []
<ChipInput
        value={chips}
        placeholder={'Escribe'}
        size={'medium'}
        variant={'outlined'}
        inputMode={'url'}
        onAdd={(chip) => handleAddChip(chip)}
        onDelete={(chip, index) => {chips.pop(index)}}
            />
```

with this function I can only type 3 elements

```
const handleAddChip = (chip) =>{
  if(chips.length <= 2){
    chips.push(chip)
  }
}
```

So the problem is when I delete one, it won't delete it until I click again over the chip input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move your chips array into your react state.  Any dynamic data that is used in your render method(s) should be part of your state.  When you update your state, react will re-render.  If you don't make this data part of your state, react will not know it needs to re-render your component so you will see stale data until something else triggers a re-render.

Alternatively, you can call `this.forceUpdate()` after you modify the chips array.  However, doing so is not recommended.

Example of state:

```
this.state = {
    chips: []
};

...

const handleAddChip = (chip) =>{
  if(this.state.chips.length <= 2) {
    this.setState({
      chips: [...this.state.chips, chip] //shorthand way to copy an array and add a new element
    });
  }
}

const handleRemoveChip = (chip) => {
  this.setState({
    chips: this.state.chips.filter(c => c != chip) //filter will produce a copy of the array
  });
}
```

The above code is intended for class based components.

If you are using function based components, you can achieve the same thing by introducing a `useState` hook.

```
function MyComponent() => {
  var [chips, setChips] = useState([]);

  const handleAddChip = (chip) => {
    if(chips.length <= 2) {
      setChips(
        [...chips, chip] //shorthand way to copy an array and add a new element
      );
    }
  }

  const handleRemoveChip = (chip) => {
    setChips(
      chips.filter(c => c != chip) //filter will produce a copy of the array
    );
  }

  return <ChipInput /* ... */ />
}
```

This is all untested code that may have errors, but should at least be a decent guide.